# github check suite to enforce a minimum pull request review period

Tags: github-actions, github-api

Our project has maintainers and reviewers with a 12 hour time difference. We have agreed to allow PRs to remain open for at least 24 hours so that everyone has a chance to review and comment. Unfortunately, this is easy to forget or overlook, especially for small PRs.

We would like to automate this as a check.

Is there an existing action, app, or check suite to enforce a minimum PR review period? (I am not interested in writing my own.)

Comment: What do you mean with "is there a check suite"? You could implement an action, an app, or look for existing actions.

Comment: @rethab Ok, then I'm interested in an existing action or app too. It doesn't have to be a check suite - I may have used the wrong term. I will reword the question. (I am not interested in writing my own.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on an enterprise plan, you can use [environment protection rules](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment#environment-protection-rules).

More specifically, configure a new environment `pr-sleeper` and set the wait time to 24 hours (1440 minutes):

[image: wait timer github config]

The second step is to create a workflow that uses the environment:

```yaml
name: Wait for 24h

on: pull_request

jobs:
  wait:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: pr-sleeper
    steps:
      - run: echo done
```

Essentially, this means the job is blocked for 24 hours and then automatically proceeds to print 'done'.

So when you now create it a PR, you'll see a check like so:

[image: wait for 24h on PR]

If you want to ensure nobody can merge before the 24 have passed, also [create a branch protection rule](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/managing-a-branch-protection-rule) for the target branch and add this as a required check.